# Angular ReactiveForm, mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here example code on stackblitz - [EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material7-template-matselect-required-jeais2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Why i cant set value in mat-select like this `this.group.patchValue({ select: { id: 2, name: 'Charmander2' } });` ?

If on example uncomment answer GPT chat it work well.

I try set data patchValue and setValue and have same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

In your template, you define the value of your select options as the `choice.id`-field:

```
<mat-option [value]="choice.id" *ngFor="let choice of choices">
```

And then in your component u try to set the value to a new object:

```
this.group.patchValue({ select: { id: 2, name: 'Charmander2' } });
```

**Solution 1:**

You need to either set the value to the id of the object you want to select, like so:

```
this.group.patchValue({ select: 2 });
```

**Solution 2:**

Or if you want to set the value of your select to the object and not only the id, you need to change your template to reference the whole object:

```
<mat-option [value]="choice" *ngFor="let choice of choices">
```

and then select the object from your choices array like so:

```
this.group.patchValue({ select: this.choices[1] });
```

Keep in mind that in the last solution you can **not** do

```
this.group.patchValue({ select: { id: 2, name: 'Charmander2' } });
```

this creates a **new object** with the same values, but you will not be able to select the **referenced object** in your select that way.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's referring to a different object, which is not one the values that are viable for selection.
If you want to treat the different objects with same properties as equal, you will have to use `compareWith` function. You can find explanation in the official docs [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection).

Answer (score 1):

You set value (just id) of item

> [value]="choice.id"

but set an object

> this.group.patchValue({ select: { id: 2, name: 'Charmander2' } });

So, you can change setting
this.group.patchValue({ select: 2});

Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/material7-template-matselect-required-frxazb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Or you can use object

> [value]="choice"

but set an object(be sure that the object belongs to sourse(array))

> this.group.patchValue({ select: this.choices[1]});

Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/material7-template-matselect-required-rgy4ux?file=src/app/app.component.ts